# Não consigo setar a página que será aberta pela função win.loadFile('')

Tags: electron

Bom dia a todos.
Sou iniciante com Electron e não estou conseguindo abrir a minha `index.html` através da função `win.loadFile()`. Simplesmente abre a seguinte tela: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Alguém poderia me explicar como resolver e por quê isto ocorre? Meu `main.js`:

```
 const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win

function createWindow () {

  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })


  win.loadFile('index.html')  


  win.webContents.openDevTools()


  win.on('closed', () => {

    win = null
  })
}


app.on('ready', createWindow)


app.on('window-all-closed', () => {

  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {

  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

UPDATE: Consegui resolver reinstalando o Electron.

Comment: A mensagem na tela diz que para você executar o app local você tem que executar o comando abaixo, chegou a fazer isso?

Comment: Cheguei a fazer sim, mas estava ocorrendo um erro. Refiz a instalação do Electron e funcionou. Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente faço da seguinte forma:

```
const electron = require('electron');

const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = electron;

let mainWindow;
let commentWindow;

app.on('ready', ()=> {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
});
```

Veja que usei uma variável do ambiente do node chamada **__dirname** que representa o diretório atual da app com a função **loadURL** que lhe possibilita não somente abrir um arquivo HTML local, como também um URL externa.

Você mencionei que reinstalou o Electron e funcinou, seu problema pode ter sido na configuração do arquivo package.json que na propriedade **scripts** deve conter a seguinte propriedade no objeto:

"nomeApp": "electron ."

Veja exemplo abaixo:

```
{
  "name": "messagebook",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "nomeApp": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^7.1.10"
  }
}
```

Desse modo acima basta você usar a seguinte linha de comando para iniciar sua App electron:

**npm rum nomeApp**

No caso nomeApp você pode trocar para o nome que quiser. Qualquer dúvida eu permaneça só atualizar.